# Joint feature QGIS 1 a N

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, dynamic, one-to-many

I have 3 tables, a linear table of sections, a non geometric table of bus lines, and a intermediate table between both, with relations N:M. In the intermediate table I have the ID of sections table and bus line table

I need to get the geometry of bus lines. but some of the sections belongs to many bus lines, so I need to "duplicate" some of the sections. I can do it with a Joint feature by field value, in the way to do a One to Many match. but the problem it's I need a dynamic way to do, that's mean, when a new link it's stablished in the intermediate table between a section and a bus line, I need to see this new entity in the geometry of bus line.

Any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer to join the 3 tables.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`, enter the following query and adjust for your layer/table name.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
 bus_line_table bl
 JOIN line_segment_relation rel ON bl.line_id = rel.line_id
 JOIN road_segments seg ON rel.segment_id = seg.segment_id
```

Comment: thanks @JGH, it's works fine! I have the bus line geometry and its update if I change the sections linked. The only problem it's the virtual layer, take to much time to draw. Every time I pan or zoom, QGIS redraws all lines, even sometimes QGIS crach or not responding. I found the "_search_frame_ ", maybe can help, but Im not sure how to include in the query. Have you any idea how to manage this problem?